# Adding days to a date in Netezza

Tags: netezza

I have a query pulling dates from field [DATE] BETWEEN '10/1/2017' AND '10/31/2017'

I want to add days to the the end date in the between criteria (10/31/2017). It seems impossible. I can add months perfectly using ADD_MONTHS, but there doesn't seem to be a function ADD_DAYS.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add_months deals with the special cases that arise from having variable length months.

For other intervals of time, things are much simpler:

To add 5 days to the current day, use this:

```
SYSTEM.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select current_date, current_date + interval '5 days';
    DATE    |      ?COLUMN?       
------------+---------------------
 2017-12-19 | 2017-12-24 00:00:00
(1 row)

T2DB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select * from interval_test where col1 between (current_timestamp - interval '2 days') and (current_timestamp + interval '3 days');
    COL1    
------------
 2017-12-19
(1 row)
```

Comment: This is what I am putting    BETWEEN '10/1/2017' AND ('10/31/2017' + interval '3 days').    I get an error back "Cannot convert entry to valid date/time; TO_DATE function might be required"

Comment: If you use a string to represent a date, and you don't explicitly cast it to a DATE , then the compiler might get confused and think it should match the only other explicitly cast item in the term (here that would be the interval).  You can either use the to_date function, or go with ::date if your format is pretty vanilla.   select * from interval_test where col1 between '10/1/2017'::date AND ('10/31/2017'::date + interval '3 days');