# Stored Procedure to delete the data prior to 7 days in Netezza

Tags: stored-procedures, netezza

I need help in creating a stored procedure in NETEZZA that should delete the data from tables prior to 7 days.

The date column across all the tables is "COB_DT".

Please advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, you can create a [stored procedure](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=structure-transaction-commits-rollbacks-in-stored-procedures) as shown in the link and ensure that within a transaction do the operations

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN_PROC
BEGIN
    // pseudocode
    find all tables from the [system views][2] 
    Use an [iterative control][3]
         DELETE from the table WHERE [date subtraction][4]


END;
END_PROC;
```

System views -> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=views-user

Iterative controls ->  https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=structures-iterative-control

Date Manipulation -> [Adding days to a date in Netezza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086539/adding-days-to-a-date-in-netezza)

The stored procedure should be called periodically either from an external client or some kind of scheduling mechanism like *cron*